# plugin not showing in wordpress..?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my comment area on single.php file in wordpress themes to allow user to comment if they are login through any social media and display their names and avatars with their comment for which i have searched for many  plugins and found this to be use full.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/
```

but the problem is that i don't understand how can i add this into the site , as i have activated it and saved all the settings but there is no short code for it to add and also it does not appears in the widgets area . thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should automatically show social icons for log in above the comment form. You need to be logged out to  see it. You also might need to configure the plugin and create apps on your social networks and provide the plugin with API keys in order to allow people to log in using social networks. You can see on this screenshot: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/screenshots/  on the networks tab you need to provide application ID and application secret keys. You will get those once you register apps on social networks.